# Mule Team explorer with Eclipse - Files not auto checked out

Tags: eclipse, tfs, mule, team-explorer, anypoint-studio

I'm using Team Explorer plug in to connect to TFS in Anypoint Studio (built on Eclipse platform I believe). When I edit the flows, files don't get checked out automatically. This is causing trouble as everyone in the team have to checkout top level folder and check-in all files for even few lines of changes.

I check the option in Windows => Preferences and everything seems to be fine.

Anyone has any resolution for this issue.

Comment: Did this phenomenon only occurs on your account and dev machine ?

Comment: all developer machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to another friend/colleague, the issue is resolved. The issue was that though it was showing connected, the IDE was assuming I was working offline mode. So we had to remove the workspace and do from start.

1. Import the project using 'Projects from Team Foundation Server' instead of creating a new workspace.
2. Select 'Team Synchronizing' perspective and 'Synchronize'.

There's still some issue though - the '.metadata' and '.mule' folders aren't part of these projects imported, so they're not checked out automatically.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must have enough permission, make sure be one of the Contributors for your team project. If this phenomenon only occurs with your machine, try to clear related cache , also try to uninstall and reinstall [the plug-in](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-team-explorer-everywhere).

Moreover, if the files don't get checked out automatically. You can still manually check out it for a workaround. Follow below steps:

1. In **Package Explorer**, select the files that you want to edit,
   open their shortcut menu, and choose **Team, Check Out for Edit.**
2. (Optional) You can lock the file.
3. Choose Check Out.

More detailed info from MSDN: [Check Out and Edit Files (Team Explorer Everywhere)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155783(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I'm not able to do manual checkout option as explained above - don't see 'checkout' option. I'm able to manually check out files from VS IDE. Sometimes adding new components or flows affect other files (pom.xml) which is not checked out automatically for developers. This is creating trouble, when they check-in only manually checked out files. Is there any way to make the Anypoint Studio/Plug-in do the auto check out?

Comment: Thanks for your time Patrick. Once I have done the above two steps, I was able to see these options.